# Running Chat Example Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websocket, chat

I'm trying to run the Chat like in the Mobile Chat Example with the sourcecode:

here:
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/webapp/mobile/chat.xhtml
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/ChatView.java?r=7770
https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/ChatUsers.java?spec=svn7780&r=7770

Now to my problem: The whole think deploy and run well but if i want to insert a username and click on "Login" the ajax-loader.gif come up and then nothing happens i never come to the Chat.
I found out that i get this response:

Error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[/index.xhtml @46,87 value="#{chatView.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'chatView' resolved to null]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
```

Where did i go wrong? please help..

BTW: I'm using Primefaces 3.4 and Glassfish 1.3.2 with enabled Websocket!

Comment: did you defined the push servlet in web.xml and placed the needed jars of atmosphere like stated in the user guide of primefaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to add some libraries.

**Solution:**
Make a complete checkout of the repository from Primefaces and it will run like on the showcase. Somehow simply coping smaller parts of it doesn't work like expected.

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/ primefaces-read-only
```

Comment: How do I go about making this complete checkout_

Comment: You can easily do a checkout here: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/checkout I'm not sure if its working at the moment, because (you see) I answered it on May 4, hope it's still working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the `ChatView` class with `@ManagedBean`. Strangely the class isn't already.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ChatView {
....
```

Comment: I tried this now and have the same problem as before!

I used the ManagedBean:
"import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;" and got an "Could not initialize class org.primefaces.push.PushContextFactory". So the page doesn't load or something!

It came to my mind that I could use the
"import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;"
and the problem now is that I want to login and nothing happend - the ChatView with ManagedBean and ViewScoped can't reach from the index.xhtml. I know that because I can't press Ctrl+Blank next to a $ or # with no suggesion - no Bean - nothing!

Is it running at your place?

Comment: @Domii please post the complete stacktrace of the "Could not initialize class..." exception. It indicates the bean can be reached from the JSF page, but somehow the `PushContextFactory` cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Domii: this is **definitely not** "the same problem as before". You're getting a completely different exception indicating a completely different problem than originally asked about (the `PropertyNotFoundException`).

Comment: I found a solution - I made a checkout of the repository from Primefaces and now it's running very well ;)